PDF of $Y=g(X)$ when $X\sim N(0,1)$. $g(X)$ is a piecewise function where each part is constant.
Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf: \begin{equation} f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \end{equation}
Now define $Y$ to be $Y=g(X)$ where $g(x)=1$ if $x>0$, $=\frac{1}{2}$ if $x=0$ and $=-1$ if $x<0$.
I want to find the pdf of $Y$. This is my attempt to find its CFD:\begin{equation} P[Y\leq y] = 1,y\geq1\\ P[Y\leq y]=f_X(0), -1\leq y < 1\\ P[Y\leq y]= 0 , y<-1 \end{equation}
The goal is then to differentiate the CFD of $Y$ to obtain its pdf, however I'm not sure if I've calculated it correctly. Can you help me please?

Sketch it out to begin with. Where do all $X >0$ map to?

Well if $X>0$ then we get that $g(X)$ is 1. It does seem like $Y$ is discrete which is odd since the book specifically asks for the pdf, not pmf.

If it's a physics or engineering book, maybe it's accepting $f_Y(y) = \tfrac{1}{2}\delta(y - 1) + \tfrac{1}{2}\delta(y + 1)$ as a pdf. But AOS has the correct solution below.

Your expression for the CDF of $Y$ is close, but should be
$$F_{Y}\left(y\right)=\begin{cases}
0, & y<-1\\
1/2, & -1\leq y<1\\
1, & y\geq1
\end{cases}.$$
Since $Y$ is discrete, it does not have a PDF.  Rather, its PMF (probability mass function) is given by
$$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\begin{cases}
1/2, & y=-1\\
1/2, & y=1
\end{cases}.$$

Thank you for answering. This is very weird since the book aks for the pdf, not pmf. The exercice in question has several $Y_i$'s to which they ask to find their pdf's. I guess it should have been more correct to  say something along the line of "find their pdf's or pmf's".

Unfortunately, some authors use the term "PDF" to include both PDFs and PMFs .

Yhea that is unfortunate. Thank you very much.
